# Project Stops working after compiling to jar

Tags: java

I currently want to try to create a .jar file that pinpoints to a .bat file to start a gaming server,

*the Forge Modloader for the current version switched from a server startup via jar file to .bat file, and my server provider currently has no solution for it.* -Small disclaimer, I haven't touched java for 6 years, which is why I may not see the obvious

For this, I found some code from Pavan.

Though, there are two problems, where I hope you may have a solution or some other workaround.
First of all, while in Intellij, "everything" works fine. `main()` is running, and the "Hallo World" Test .bat is opening. After compiling it to a jar, nothing happens, even with a set File Path.

Second Problem. I've tried several spots, but `System.exit(0)` does not work, after

```
int returnCode = CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine(commandLine, systemOut, systemErr);
```

The code basically stops, and the process stays inactive, which could end up bad for a gaming server where I have 0 access to the needed tools to clean this up by myself... and I don't want to explain to Customer Support why there are 1000 instances of java running in the background ;)

But regardless, Thanks for your time and hopefully help as well

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineException;
import org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils;
import org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.Commandline;
import org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.WriterStreamConsumer;

public class BatRunner {
    public BatRunner() {
        String batfile = "run.bat";
        String directory = "C:\\Users\\User\\IdeaProjects";
        try {
             runProcess(batfile, directory);           
        } catch (CommandLineException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void runProcess(String batfile, String directory) throws CommandLineException {

        Commandline commandLine = new Commandline();

        File executable = new File(directory + "/" +batfile);
        commandLine.setExecutable(executable.getAbsolutePath());

        WriterStreamConsumer systemOut = new WriterStreamConsumer(
                new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));

        WriterStreamConsumer systemErr = new WriterStreamConsumer(
                new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));

        int returnCode = CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine(commandLine, systemOut, systemErr);
        System.exit(0);
        if (returnCode != 0) {
            System.out.println("Something Bad Happened!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Taaa!! ddaaaaa!!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BatRunner();
    }
}
```

Source: https://www.opencodez.com/java/how-to-execute-bat-file-from-java.htm/